# Difference between Parse.Object.saveAll(objects) and Parse.Promise.when(promiseListOfSaves)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I've got a cloud code function which marks Notification objects as "read" and then queries the same class immediately for remaining "unread" objects.

The problem is the **most** times, the same Notification objects I mark as read are returned in my preceding unread query, even if the values have been updated in data browser.

When I changed from `Parse.Promise.when()` to `Parse.Object.saveAll()`, that solved the issue, but it's still unclear why. The when promise is supposed to be resolved when all the `save()` operations complete and hence will not run the last "unread" query until they've been marked as read.

What does `Parse.Object.saveAll(objects)` do that `Parse.Promise.when(promiseListOfSaves)` doesn't?

Code examples of each below. Not much difference between the two aside from the way objects are being saved.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('markThreadReadAndReturnUnreadCount', function(request, response){

    var promiseChain = [];
    var Notification = Parse.Object.extend("Notification");
    qry = new Parse.Query(Notification);
    qry.equalTo('owner', request.user);
    qry.equalTo('read', false);
    qry.equalTo('messageThreadId', request.params.threadId);
    qry.find(null, {useMasterKey: true}).then(function(_notifications){
        _.each(_notifications, function(_notification){
            notification = new Notification();
            notification.id = _notification.id;
            notification.set('read', true);
            promiseChain.push(notification.save(null, {wait: true}));
        });
        return Parse.Promise.when(promiseChain);
    }).then(function(){
        var countUnreadQuery = new Parse.Query(Notification);
        countUnreadQuery.equalTo('owner', user);
        countUnreadQuery.equalTo('read', false);
        countUnreadQuery.find({useMasterKey: true}).then(function(results){
            return response.success(results.length);
        }
    };

});
```

with Parse.Object.saveAll();

```
Parse.Cloud.define('markThreadReadAndReturnUnreadCount', function(request, response){

    var saveObjects = [];
    var Notification = Parse.Object.extend("Notification");
    qry = new Parse.Query(Notification);
    qry.equalTo('owner', request.user);
    qry.equalTo('read', false);
    qry.equalTo('messageThreadId', request.params.threadId);
    qry.find(null, {useMasterKey: true}).then(function(_notifications){
        _.each(_notifications, function(_notification){
            notification = new Notification();
            notification.id = _notification.id;
            notification.set('read', true);
            saveObjects.push(notification);
        });
        return Parse.Object.saveAll(saveObjects);
    }).then(function(){
        var countUnreadQuery = new Parse.Query(Notification);
        countUnreadQuery.equalTo('owner', user);
        countUnreadQuery.equalTo('read', false);
        countUnreadQuery.find({useMasterKey: true}).then(function(results){
            return response.success(results.length);
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: I made some copy edits mostly just to break up the one long paragraph into multiple paragraphs for better readability, in the spirit of trying help make sure you get a good answer here. (Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way.)

Comment: @Tariq, I guess you need to update the second block of code to `Object.saveAll`

Comment: Thanks @mido22. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why `saveAll` works where `when` doesn't work, but I would prefer `saveAll` over `when` in this scenario for two reasons:

1. The code style, what looks better of the two options below:

   ```
   function save(objects){
       return Parse.Promise.when(objects.map(function(object){
           return object.save(null, {wait: true});
       }));
   }

   // or

   function save(objects){
       return Parse.Object.saveAll(objects);
   }
   ```
2. Performance, when you use an array of save, you send `n` http requests for the `n` objects you want to save, this is a huge waste of resources, but when you use `saveAll` you send only one request for all of them.

also I think your second code can be reduced to:

```
...
qry.find(null, {useMasterKey: true}).then(function(_notifications){
    _.each(_notifications, function(_notification){
        notification.set('read', true);
    });
    return Parse.Object.saveAll(_notifications);
}).then(function(){
...
```

Comment: I think the main point is number 2. Read [Parse.Object.saveAll vs Parse.Promise.when](https://www.parse.com/questions/parseobjectsaveall-vs-parsepromisewhen)

Comment: The network call optimization makes total sense. I'm still unclear why a `Parse.Promise.when()` resolves before the save operations in the promise chain actually complete? At least, that's what seems to be happening.

Comment: @TariqZabian try chaining each `save` with `console.log`, see if they all get executed before `then` of `Promise.when`...